# how to display image on a form select box change

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I'm trying to created a select box in my form and display the image that is selected in the select box next to it. I know it requires jquery or something and I have no clue when it comes to that. If anyone can help or point me in the right direction that would be awesome!!!

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select id="icon" name="icon" class="form-control select2">
            <?php foreach ($icons as $icon) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $icon['link']; ?>">
                    <?php echo $icon['name']; ?>
                </option>
            <?php } ?>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td align="center" id="iconPreview">
            Image Here
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

i found this jquery snippet but it doesn't display anything on change...

JQuery:

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#icon").change(function() {
         $("#iconPreview").empty();
         if ( $("#icon").val()!="" ){
            $("#iconPreview").append("<img src=\"" + $("#icon").val()  + "\" />");
         }
         else{
            $("#iconPreview").append("displays image here");
         }
       });
     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add jQuery if you want to use jQuery in the head, so in your document in the `<head>` add this line:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
```

Then give the TD you want the image in a class:

```
<td class="imageHere" align="center" id="seleced_image">
```

Then, at the bottom of your page (or a .js page if you want to link it) add this:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#icon').change(function(){
            var image = $('#icon').val();
            $('#seleced_image').html("<img src='" + image + "' alt='description' />");
        });
    });
</script>
```

This jQuery is saying "Everytime the `#icon` dropdown changes, load the image into the `<td>`

This is the simplest way to do it without learning any jQuery.  Otherwise, I suggest you learn jQuery or better yet, javascript.

Changes made:
Its better to work with IDs than classes on cases like this.

Comment: looks simple but i the link for the image is coming from php, so how could i add that in instead of setting the path in the `image` variable in the jquery code?

Comment: You can load the image with PHP and make it hidden with CSS, then you'll be able to pull the image src using `var image = $('.image').src();` and use it that way

Comment: @rackemup420, Keep in mind, this is all just off the top of my head and is probably not the best way to do this, especially if you have a lot of TDs and a lot of images.  But I can only answer the question you give.

Comment: at the most there will be lets say 10 images in the select box. im lost on where to add `var image = $('.image').src();` can you update your answer with it in there and a snippet of how it gets called in php? im a little confused lol

Comment: @rackemup420, Ok, I've updated my answer to show where the image is pulling the image source from.  I am assuming the image source is the actual value of the select box?

Comment: yes its the value. i added this code in and nothing seems to happen.

Comment: Try adding `alert($);` directly under the `$('#icon').change(function(){` line.  When you select something in the icon box, it should show an alert box.

Comment: oh, sorry - have you wrapped the javascript in <script> tags?  I'll update the answer

Comment: Ok, replace all of the script under `$(function(){` with just `alert($);`.  Does that do anything?

Comment: i have `jQuery-2.1.4.min.js` is that the same as `jquery-1.12.0.min.js`? or should i include `jquery-1.12.0.min.js` as well?

Comment: No, you have a newer version of jQuery.  We just have to figure out how to make it show...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101630/discussion-between-ntgcleaner-and-rackemup420).

Comment: adding just `alert($);` under the function did nothing as well